# is it possible to store form values in a drop down list in django

Tags: python, django

I am using django to make a questions application, I am allowing users to add questions to the site with a couple of optional answers for each question that are defined by the user who made the question. I am wanting to display the optional answers in a drop down box. but I keep getting an error from my model saying option one is not defined.

choice modal

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    CHOICES = (
        (option_one,option_one),
        (option_two,option_two),

    )
    user_choice = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=CHOICES,
        default=Yes,
    )

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.user_choice
```

view

```
def create_poll(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePollForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.cleaned_data['question']
            option_one = form.cleaned_data['option_one']
            option_two = form.cleaned_data['option_two']
            print option_one
            q = Question.objects.create(question_text=question)
            o = Choice.objects.create(question=q, option_one=option_one,option_two=option_two)
            q.save()
            o.save

            form = CreatePollForm()
            return render(request, 'polls/createPolls_form.html', {'form':form})

    form = CreatePollForm()
    return render(request,'polls/createPolls_form.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class CreatePollForm(forms.Form):
        question = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_one = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_two = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: If you have `choices` argument, and you're trying to provide custom value then your form validation would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to remove the default choices and then try same:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_choice = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        default=Yes,
    )

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.user_choice
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using option_one as a variable and that's not defined. you can use it as a string like 'option_one' or can define it earlier like option_one = 'whatever you want to define.....'